# Android NDK build path not found

Tags: android, path, android-ndk, cygwin

I see the error as shown in the screenshot when I try to build the NDK OpenCV Android program. I have added the lines:

NDK_HOME=C:\android-ndk-rd8 
export NDK_HOME

to my .bashrc file in cygwin. I am working on Windows 7 and my NDK is at C:\android-ndk-rd8

I thought adding the above lines would fix it, but it didn't work. How do I get the program to compile? Do I have to change the PATH variable? If so, how exactly do I do that?[image]

Comment: Your .bashrc is a bit suspect, the backslash may well need to be escaped (or use a forward slash), and you definitely need a semicolon between the assignment and the export command if they are on the same line.  However, this would only be relevant for tools started from the bash command line - if you are starting eclipse as a normal windows app, it would be completely unaware of variables exported by some bash session that might be running concurrently, as exports are only inherited by process children.

Answer (score 4):

From your error log I suppose you should specify SA environment variable, you can do it in eclipse properties for your project:

> Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Enviroment -> Here press button
>   Add.. -> and put Name: SA with Value: path to your NDK folder

Answer (score 1):

I think, from Eclipse environmental variables are referred something like `{env:NDK_HOME}`. In Properties|C++|Build or something like that

Comment: What exactly do you mean? My build command set under Properties->C++->Build is C:/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build.cmd  and Build location is ${workspace_loc:/OpenCV Sample - face-detection}